# Creating Bitmap Image in Ribbon button

Tags: mfc, ribbon-control

I created MFC SDI ribbon project with VS Professional 2022. How can I add a button with custom bitmap file in the ribbon? In the property window of the button, only some already given bitmaps are shown, so cannot add my own bitmap.

Comment: See the [Windows Ribbon Framework Developer Guides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/windowsribbon/windowsribbon-guides-entry) to learn how this control works. If you are indeed using a ribbon control rather than a [toolbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/toolbar-control-reference) control.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what is your problem? What keeps you from altering the "already given" bitmaps?

Comment: @thomielAlready given bitmaps

Comment: @thomiel    Aready given bitmaps are only few in number. I need more numbers of bitmaps.   In the image list under properties of  the button, only the already given bitmaps are shown. Please tell steps to be followed to add images to the image list.

Comment: You might want to follow the steps explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277340/how-to-add-icons-to-mfc-ribbon-buttons) answer.